AndraX and ifconfig thinks that is wlan0 is ethernet
When i tries to execute:
airodump-ng wlan0 .

It says, that i can not run it:
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Invalid argument
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Invalid argument
Error setting monitor mode on wlan0
Failed initializing wireless card(s): wlan0


There is ifconfig output:
wlan0: flags=2<BROADCAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 42:a2:d1:cb:4f:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1263117  bytes 1556415288 (1.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 237716  bytes 60583917 (57.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Does it caused by wrong driver. Or wireless module doesn't have monitor mode. (Device is Realme C21Y, if somedy have it... Maybe)

Welcome to SuperUser. Please read the tag guidance for the Android tag. If your question is still on-topic here based on the instructions in that tag, please EDIT your post to indicate why that is the case.

What does iw phy report about the capabilities of the interface/driver? Does it list monitor under "Supported interface modes"?

Thanks, no monitor mode in iw phy: Supported interface modes:                  * IBSS                  * managed                  * AP                  * P2P-client                  * P2P-GO                  * P2P-device
